# Can the tensor.item() differ when representing the same value of a tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

Declare a tensor such as a=tensor.tensor([0.123], dtype=tensor.tensor32) and print a.item(), 0.12300000339746475 is printed. Is this a unique value or a value that depends on the calculation process?

I checked that c=a+b has same c.item() value when
a=torch.tensor([0.123],dtype=torch.float32), b=torch.tensor([0.00045],dtype=torch.float32) and a=torch.tensor([0.10305],dtype=torch.float32), b=torch.tensor([0.0204],dtype=torch.float32).
But I'm not sure it's always work.

And, I wonder if the value of tensor.item() is used for calculation or only when printing.

I would appreciate your reply. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`.item()` [Returns the value of this tensor as a standard Python number](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html).

The value you are getting is due to numerical accuracy, you cannot represent all numbers.
If you try for example:

```
import torch
a=torch.tensor([0.123], dtype=torch.float64)
a.item()
```

you will get the same value.